# Python create filenames without parentheses and quotes

Tags: python, csv

So i am new to Python and found below script. I adjusted it in such a way that its creating files based on 2 values ; account_code and account.
However, the files that are created are looking like
('account_code','account').csv / ('blablabla','123').csv.

I tried multiple things with strip etc but to no avail. How would i be able to remove parentheses / quotes from the file name?

```
import csv

with open(r"Outbox\file.csv") as fin:    
    csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
    # Category -> open file lookup
    outputs = {}
    for row in csvin:
        cat = row['account_code'],row['account']
        # Open a new file and write the header
        if cat not in outputs:
            fout = open('{}.csv'.format(cat), 'w',newline='')
            dw = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=csvin.fieldnames)
            dw.writeheader()
            outputs[cat] = fout, dw
        # Always write the row
        outputs[cat][1].writerow(row)
    # Close all the files
    for fout, _ in outputs.values():
        fout.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cat = row['account_code'], row['account']`, it is creating a tuple containing `row['account_code']` and `row['account']` (in this order), not a string (because it is not already a string). Then, in `'{}.csv'.format(cat)`, cat will be transformed to a string using it's own string representation function (`__repr__`), which is `('account_code','account')`.

You should make `cat` become a string, then something like this would do the job.

```py
cat = '{}_{}'.format(row['account_code'],row['account'])
```